# Hide children field when serializing toArray [Laravel 5.3]

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization) (Section: *Temporarily Modifying Attribute Visibility*) that we can hide object properties temporarily.

Is it possible to also hide children attributes?

For example:

```
//User model
class User extends \App\AppModel
{
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
    }
}
```

Exclude from array here:

```
$user = User::find($id);

$userData = $user->makeHidden(['last_name', 'articles.*.user_id'])->toArray();
dd($userData); //user_id still present in articles :(
```

Comment: `dd($userData);` should only include the attributes from the User model/class so I'm not sure how you're seeing attributes from your Article class. Did you post all the applicable code? Is your \App\AppModel class doing something special?

Comment: @anakadote Thanks for the reply. _"To convert a model and its loaded relationships to an array, you should use the toArray method. This method is recursive, so all attributes and all relations (including the relations of relations) will be converted to arrays"_ from the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#serializing-models-and-collections) . AppModel is only extending default eloquent model and defining which connection it will use `protected $connection = 'pgsql';`

Comment: You should still need to include `with('articles')`, no? See my answer below for a working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$userData = User::with('articles')->where('id', $id)->get()->each(function($user){
    $user->articles->makeHidden(['user_id']);
})->makeHidden(['last_name'])->toArray();

dd($userData);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like

```
$userData->articles = $user->articles()->get()->each(function($item){
    $item->makeHidden(['user_id']); 
});

dd($userData);
```

Comment: This answer was really close to the solution. Thank you anyway